# Getting lowest integer from other integers

Tags: java, integer, int

Alright, let me try to explain as well as I possibly can here.
Lets say I have for integers, A, B, C, D. Any of these integers are random integers 1-10. So each one of these will be 1-10.

I want to find the lowest integer out of A B C D. **But** heres the *tricky part*, when one of the variables(a,b,c, or d) is the same as another one, and they are both the lowest variables. Then it will have to take those variables and choose a random between them. I have tried so many times but can't get it, any suggestions or code for me to try?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far, and where it failed?

Comment: When you say _choose a random between them_ do you mean _choose **at** random between them_?

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question posted minutes ago.Do the follow:
1) put these elements in an array an d order them (ascending order)
2) starting for the first position look how many equals element there are. 
3) if there are two , use the Random class to choose randomly between 1 and 2 
4) if the random element got is 2 pick the second element of your array, else if it is one, pick the first.

I hope it is clear.
bye

Answer (score 0):

The below code sorts an array of random `int`s between 1 and 10 into order (lowest to highest) and compares the two lowest `int`s. If they are the same it prints one of the two at random, otherwise it just prints the lowest value;

```
public class LowestInt {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        int b = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        int c = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        int d = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;

        int arrayOf[] = {a,b,c,d};
        Arrays.sort(arrayOf);

        if(arrayOf[0] == arrayOf[1]) {
            System.out.println(arrayOf[(int)(Math.random()*1)]);
        } else {
            System.out.println(arrayOf[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

To get a random `int` from either of the two lowest indexes in the array we just access the array using a random `int` between 0 and 1.

It is worth asking yourself though "*Why choose from the two lowest at random?*". They will always be the same value so you wouldn't know which of the two were picked anyway. It doesn't seem to make any difference.

I hope this helps.